# How do i do numpy.savetxt with string and engineering notation numbers correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to save a txt file with engineering notation numbers and string between. Here is the numpy array what i want to save:

```
[['Tempo Longitudinal' 'Tempo Transversal' 'Birrefringência']
 ['4.517156250000001e-06' '4.522725e-06' '0.0012320405204435802']
 ['4.51608125e-06' '4.5209375e-06' '0.001074746027278091']
 ['4.5155125e-06' '4.520812499999999e-06' '0.0011730432449029704']
 ['4.522668749999999e-06' '4.52531875e-06' '0.0005857656191502759']]
```

Here is my code i tried to save it

```
import numpy as np

rawTLc = np.asarray(['Tempo Longitudinal','4.517156250000001e-06','4.51608125e-06','4.5155125e-06','4.522668749999999e-06'])
rawTTc = np.asarray(['Tempo Transversal','4.522725e-06','4.5209375e-06','4.520812499999999e-06','4.52531875e-06'])
rawbirc = np.asarray( ['Birrefringência','0.0012320405204435802','0.001074746027278091','0.0011730432449029704','0.0005857656191502759'])

savefile = np.vstack((rawTLc, rawTTc))
savefile = np.vstack((savefile, rawbirc))
savefile = np.transpose(savefile)

np.savetxt('savedir',savefile, delimiter='\t',fmt='%s')
```

It save the txt file well, but i want to know a better way to do it, with only 6 significant figures and keeping the strings.

Comment: A minor cleanup: `savefile = np.column_stack([rawTLc, rawTTc, rawbirc])`

Comment: Looks like the strings are column headers.  How about formatting them as `header` string?  Then use the desired float format for the data.

Comment: I tried that, but can i make a header to each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [398]: savefile = np.column_stack([rawTLc, rawTTc, rawbirc])                      
In [399]: head=', '.join(savefile[0,:])                                              
In [400]: arr = savefile[1:,:].astype(float)                                         
In [401]: np.savetxt('test',arr, fmt='%16.6e', delimiter=',', header=head, comments='')                                                                         
In [402]: cat test                                                                   
Tempo Longitudinal, Tempo Transversal, Birrefringência
    4.517156e-06,    4.522725e-06,    1.232041e-03
    4.516081e-06,    4.520938e-06,    1.074746e-03
    4.515513e-06,    4.520812e-06,    1.173043e-03
    4.522669e-06,    4.525319e-06,    5.857656e-04
```